# Calculating confidence intervals for proportions

Tags: r, confidence-interval, proportion

I have national level data for 4 questions. The questions are Likert scale 1-5 (strongly disagree, disagree, and so on..) Im trying to calculate confidence intervals for munnicipalities for the proportions that have anserwed 4 or 5 to those specific questions. I used prop.test in R like this:

```
angry2.5 = prop.test(sum(!is.na(angry) & angry %in% c(4, 5)), 
  sum(!is.na(angry)))$conf.int[1]
angry97.5 = prop.test(sum(!is.na(angry) & angry %in% c(4, 5)), 
  sum(!is.na(angry)))$conf.int[2]
```

I'm wondering is this right or is this "good" only for binary questions? `Prop.test` uses Wilson score interval with continuity correction. The CIs are not symmetric for smaller municipalities probably since the proportions are closer to one for this question.

Is there a better alternative for `prop.test` I could use in R?

Comment: I wasn’t aware that you really needed a continuity correction for the wonderful Wilson confidence interval.  But more to your question, treating 4 and 5 as the same by unioning them is probably less informative than treating the Likert scale as interval-scaled and computing the mean.  You might need to use the bootstrap to get a confidence interval for the mean because of discreteness.